# Getting sbt-assembly working

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, typesafe-stack, sbt-assembly

So thus far I've been compiling my Scala project with SBT (via Typesafe stack). I want to run the code across several machines now, via [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). Following directions, the only one change I made was in my `project/Build.scala` file. Here is the related part:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases",
resolvers += "artifactory" at "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases",
libraryDependencies += "com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.8.3"
```

When I run `sbt compile` however, I get this error:

`sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2;0.8.3: not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

*EDIT*
Created a `build.sbt` file in the same folder as `Build.scala` (folder is `/project/`) and have these two lines in it:

```
Seq[Setting[_]](resolvers += "artifactory" at "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases",
                addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.8.3"))
```

Now the error is:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.8.3 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/Users/myname/current/projectname/project/}default-d7da9a/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.8.3: not found
```

*EDIT 2*
Hm, after I do a successful `sbt compile`, should I just be able to enter the `sbt` console and type in `assembly`?

```
> assembly
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Not a valid configuration: assembly
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

*EDIT 3* JK got it. Had to add the `build.sbt` info as specified in the GitHub README.

Comment: "info as specified in the GitHub README" - link please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two points here.  One is that SBT plugins are not *just* library dependencies -- in particular, they use the current SBT version in a similar way that other Scala libraries use the Scala version.  The other is that `libraryDependencies` in `project/Build.scala` affects the dependencies for the *project*, not for the *build*.

An SBT full build is itself an SBT project, just located one level down the directory tree, and so can have a build of its own configured the same way a normal build is.  Unlike a normal build, where going for a "full build" is necessary under a handful of circumstances, there is almost never a reason to use a full build for a build, so using `.sbt` files located in `project/` is almost always sufficient.

The other issue is the versioning.  SBT has a utility function called `addSbtPlugin` that handles everything for you.  It takes a moduleID and adds all the necessary SBT and Scala versioning information.

So, to get sbt-assembly working in a full build, you create a `.sbt` file in under `project/` (conventionally either `project/build.sbt` or `project/plugins.sbt`) and place your build's resolvers and dependencies there:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("artifactory", url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.8.3")
```

Comment: What is the format of the arguments to `addSbtPlugin`? What would I do for `sbt-assembly`?

Comment: `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.8.3")`, so the part of your build.scala that deals with settings should look like:

Seq[Setting[_]](resolvers += ..., resolvers += ..., addSbtPlugin(...))`

Comment: Actually, it suddenly occurs to me that you might be putting it in the wrong file altogether.  If this is project/Build.scala, then putting it in there will do no good at all (it will declare that your _source code_ depends on sbt-assembly, not the project).  To make the project use it, put the settings for it either in project/build.sbt or project/project/Build.scala (preferably the former, as there is almost never a reason to use a full build for the project's meta-build).

Comment: Hm, do I do the `Seq[Setting[_]]` on the entire `settings` assignment, or just the part for the `sbt-assembly` plugin? *EDIT* Just got your new message.. let me try again.

Comment: So should I just create a `build.sbt` in the same folder as my `Build.scala` file, add those 2 lines, and then do `sbt compile`?

Comment: Yes; I'm editing my answer now to make this (and the reason for it) clearer.

Comment: I've edited my original question to reflect new errors... thanks for your help!

Comment: There, done editing.  To answer your new question: remove the "Seq[Setting](" from the first line, the comma, and the final closing parenthesis at the end, and put a blank line between the two.